# Genesis block/ledger on stellar-core

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-laboratory

I am looking at how to generate the Genesis block/ledger on stellar-core.

I have seen people suggest pre-populating the database, what is the easiest option for a newbie to stellar-core.

Answer (score 0):

Genesis ledger is created when you first initiate the database by running `stellar-core new-db`, so you do not need to populate it manually.